# How to "diff" components included in managed package versions

Tags: managed-package, api, deployment, ide, package

I'm trying to get a "diff"-like view of all components added in subsequent releases of a managed package. I know that the PackageVersion type, and its related types, are available through the Metadata API, but these don't seem to be available through Eclipse. Any tools or methods out there I'm missing for getting a side-by-side comparison view of the components included in two package versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think unless you have got the package already in a source control system you will need to manually diff the two package versions yourself. If you have the package codebase downloaded you could use something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) (Free No-Frills diff program for Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from reviewing them on the package manager on the website, or the complaints that the packaging process issues - your going to need to get your code into some sort of version control.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, guess that's about what I expected to hear :)